# kube apiserver timeout Error cleaning up secrets resource name may not be empty

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, gitlab, cicd

When I trigger publish on gitlab, it fails and I check the logs of gitlab-runner pod, It shows the error below:

```
kubectl logs -n gitlab-tur prod-gitlab-ci-runner-0
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Post https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/gitlab-tur/secrets: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout  duration=1m0.007641837s job=3044 project=25 runner=DwvfWx49
ERROR: Error cleaning up secrets: resource name may not be empty  job=3044 project=25 runner=DwvfWx49
```

Here is the screenshot
[image]

Version Info:

```
root@ubuntu:~# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.4", GitCommit:"8d8aa39598534325ad77120c120a22b3a990b5ea", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-12T21:03:42Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.4", GitCommit:"8d8aa39598534325ad77120c120a22b3a990b5ea", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-12T20:55:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I am not able to publish anything to environments for days. Has anyone experienced such a problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a workaround for that by deleting the gitlab-runner pod in k8s and retrying the process as per [this post](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-runner-error-error-cleaning-up-secrets-resource-name-may-not-be-empty/33078).

Comment: Thx for your contribution but I already tried it, It throws the same error.

Comment: @ProjectMayhem were you able to find any solution?

Comment: It’s some kind of bug in kubeapiserver. I had to reboot all services and now it is working